# C# Using mapper to map a DataReader to an object

Tags: c#, sqlite, automapper

I've been struggling with getting ExpressMapper to map from a DataReader to a object (basically, Sqlite Rows -> Objects) . I've had success with AutoMapper, but found some other issues that got me looking for another map tool.

In AutoMapper I used the following code, but in ExpressMapper all string properties are NULL and the long prop is always 0, this indicates that the mapping is failing. Tried to look some examples for ExpressMapper but did not found any. Can you help? 
Also, are there any other mappers besides AutoMapper (and possibly ExpressMapper) that can help me achieve this scenario?

Thanks!

```
 public class ImportedFiles
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public String Hash { get; set; }

    public ImportedFiles()
    {

    }

}

private static void ReadImportedFiles()
    {
        var lst = ReadData<ImportedFiles>("SELECT * FROM ImportedFiles").ToList();
    }

 public static IEnumerable<T> ReadData<T>(string queryString)
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = queryString;
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                            while (reader.Read())
                                yield return Mapper.Map<IDataRecord, T>(reader);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Do you need help with Automapper or ExpressMapper?  Once you determine which one you need help with, please show example code (and probably some sample data) that reproduces the problem you need help with.

Comment: Concerning Expressmapper: Unfortunately Expressmapper doesn't support mapping DataReader to Object yet. The main issue that IDataRecord every time could have different column names per DataReader that force Expressmapper to compile mappings per each DataReader without cache, but I think still it is double to make caching work, so I've just registered the issue: https://github.com/expressmapper/ExpressMapper/issues/74 on the Github that probably will be included with Release 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

> are there any other mappers besides AutoMapper (and possibly ExpressMapper) that can help me achieve this scenario?

Yes. Generally, they are called **Object-Relational Mappers** (shortened to O/RM or just ORM).  There are many; a couple of the most popular for the .NET framework are [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/).

I think you are using the wrong *class* of tool (object-to-object mappers) for the task at hand ([object-relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)).

Object-to-object mappers are designed for mapping between closely aligned, strongly-typed, data-containing classes, usually to save hand-writing mapping code.  They are not designed for mapping to or from more generic data containers like `DataRow`, or for dealing with other "plumbing" concerns that come into play when working with a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

ExpressMapper is capable to map to a DataRow.
This should solves your issue.

Just refactor your code to work with a DataRow. And pre-register the mapping.

So, if you write:

```
yield return Mapper.Map<DataRow, T>(row);
```

And do the mappings (once per application) like I suggested:

```
        Mapper.Register<DataRow, ImportedFiles>()
            .Member(dest => dest.Id,
                    src => DBNull.Value == src["Id"] ? 0 : (double)src["Id"])
            .Member(dest => dest.FileName,
                    src => DBNull.Value == src["FileName"] ? String.Empty : (string)src["FileName"])
            .Member(dest => dest.Hash,
                    src => DBNull.Value == src["Hash"] ? String.Empty : (string)src["Hash"])
            ;
```

You're able to use it.

---

[Edited]

In case you need to map more than one source (i.e.: more than one DataTable) then you could write a DataRowAdapter which will differentiate your mapping and let know ExpressMapper (or whatever ORM you want to use - this is appliable to all ORM) which data to expect in your DataRow.

Below a working example with your code.

```
yield return Mapper.Map<DataRowAdapter<T>, T>(new DataRowAdapter<T>(row));
```

DataRowAdapter class:

```
public class DataRowAdapter<T>
{
    DataRow _dataRow;

    public DataRowAdapter(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        _dataRow = dataRow;
    }

    public DataRow Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataRow;
        }
    }
}
```

And your new-brand mapping:

```
     Mapper.Register<DataRowAdapter<ImportedFiles>, ImportedFiles>()
        .Member(dest => dest.Id,
                src => DBNull.Value == src.Current["Id"] ? 0 : (double)src.Current["Id"])
        .Member(dest => dest.FileName,
                src => DBNull.Value == src.Current["FileName"] ? String.Empty : (string)src.Current["FileName"])
        .Member(dest => dest.Hash,
                src => DBNull.Value == src.Current["Hash"] ? String.Empty : (string)src.Current["Hash"])
        ;
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Example using SQLiteData reader to map the selected items to  Object class List

```
public static List<Object.Class> getObject()
    {
        List<Object.Class> list = new List<Object.Class>();
        var datareader = Database.getData();
        while (datareader.Read())
        {


            list.Add(item: new Object.Class(
               id: datareader.GetInt32(0),
            date: DateTime.Parse(datareader.GetString(6))
                )
        );


        }
        datareader.Close();

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).